# Erratic error with PHP and Doctrine

Tags: php, memory, doctrine-orm

I tried to find some information on Google regarding this weird fatal PHP error happening randomly when running one of my projects.

**Class 'Doctrine\ORM\ORMException' not found in Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php on line 1341**

**Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 47877190154432 bytes) in Unknown on line 0**

These errors happen without any logic when displaying a page for which source and processed data remain the same from one call to another and where sometime the script:

- runs perfectly fine,
- sometime fails during transfer,
- sometime fails before the server could send any data (including HTTP headers),
- sometime work fine but makes subsequent ajax call from within the rendered HTML fail

I checked log files, but could not find any clue about why this happens.

Could someone tell me if he faced this kind of issue and/or tell me things I could check in order to solve this annoying issue, please?

EDIT: seems to be a Smarty related issue with precompilation...

Comment: Do you transfer large files or are you storing files into the database or do you eval()?

Comment: The error message says PHP tried to allocate 47877 gigabytes of RAM! Not surprisingly, it failed.

Comment: Do you try to print out Doctrine objects (for logging)? This can produce endless recursions, because two objects are dependent from another

Comment: @DelPedro : no, not any of this. The page is called via a simple GET without parameters. There is no file manipulation, and no eval().

Comment: @Jocelyn. I also noticed this. But, be sure I did not try, my server does not own such an amount of RAM! :)

Comment: @DanLee No, I'm not trying to print out Doctrine objects. By the way if I had to, I would have used \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump() to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Doctrine is keeping too many objects in memory (hence persistence) and you need to write some management code that flushes persistent objects you don't need to use. Or make sure Doctrine is using the file system instead of memory to store persistant objects.